# Angular 2, How can I set the target div of routing element?

Tags: angularjs, routes, target

How can I set the target ("div") of the selected routing element. I would like to see the selected content is population in the target div.

in **app-routing.module.ts**
...

```
const appRouting: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: './component/aboutme', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'aboutme', component: AboutmeComponent },
  { path: 'dev-masm', component: DevMasmComponent}
];
```

**app.component.html**
...

```
<div id="Header">My page</div>
<div id="Content">

</div>
<div id="Menu">
  <a routerLink="/aboutme" routerLinkActive="active">About me</a><br>
  <a routerLink="/dev-masm" routerLinkActive="active">MASM.</a><br>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Came up in my mind an idea, I move the "<router-outlet></router-outlet>" to that div where I want to see the selected route item content, it seems works. Is there available any idea for it?